# Codesign command error code meaning

Tags: ios

For the codesign command, where can I see what the numbered error code meanings? I'm exit status 1 and exit status 74. I'm curious on what these mean.

Comment: Which command are you running exactly ? There are some info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW11) but no error code.

Comment: I want to run "codesign"